# Select printer serverside in web application

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-sdk, npapi, printing-web-page

I have a webapp with "print invoice" and "print receipt" functions.

How could I accomplish to print in the thermal printer for printing receipts but using the laser printer for invoices 100% silently?

I understand this isn't possible without any client side software previously loaded installed, this functionality is needed just for certain computers. It doesn't matter if the solution is browser specific or OS specific. Also I understand "kiosk mode" allows me to print silently to the default printer.

I have no idea what could be a good solution but was thinking about a Chrome extension or Firefox addon with a custom printing function where I could trigger from javascript like

```
my_custom_print('printer_b')
```

or

```
my_custom_print('printer_a')
```

Still I have no idea if that is even possible with extensions/addons or need something like NPAPI, PPAPI, java applets, etc...
Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm about 90% sure that you can't silently print to a printer using any technology built into the browser; since NPAPI doesn't work in Chrome anymore (as of version 45) and PPAPI was never something you could use to call native APIs unless you want to pass in special command line flags to enable your plugin, Native Messaging is most likely what you'd need to use for this.